# Flex transitions target all elements

Tags: apache-flex

I want to fade all the elements of the next state when transitioning from any state.
I tried different things but I can't get it to work. And I don't want to manually add transitions for every state.

Something like:

```
<s:Transition fromState="*" toState="*">
        <s:Fade target="*" duration="500" />
    </s:Transition>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey, mihaimetal.  I just found your post after struggling with this same thing myself.  It turns out that the best way to do this is not to use the `target` property, but the `targets` one instead.  This way, you can pass a whole Array of things that *may* be changed.  I emphasize 'may', because only the items you give in the Array you pass to `targets` that are actually changed between states will will be affected.

You can change your sample code like so:

```
<s:Transition fromState="*" toState="*">
    <s:Fade targets="{[hboxID_1, hboxID_2, hboxID_3]}" duration="500" />
</s:Transition>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Same question.

Bunch of screens attached to states, one screen at a time. Instead of abrupt switch on state change I want a simple fade.

Tried wildcard in target:

```
target="*"
```

in targets:

```
targets="{['*']}"
```

and tried removing targets/target

Nada

This works, but I don't want to id all states and track list of targets.

Here is a sample:

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="default" stateGroups="sessionless"/>
    <s:State name="Welcome" stateGroups="session" />
    <s:State name="Settings" stateGroups="session" />
</s:states>
<s:Panel includeIn="sessionless">
    <comp:Login id="login" includeIn="Login" />
</s:Panel>
<s:Panel includeIn="session">
    <comp:Welcome id="welcome" includeIn="Welcome" />
    <comp:Settings id="settings" includeIn="Settings" />
</s:Panel>
<s:transitions><s:Transition id="fader" fromState="*" toState="*">
    <s:Fade duration="4000" targets="{[settings,login,welcome]}" />
</s:Transition></s:transitions>
```

Comment: I don't mean to be offensive, but that sounds rather lazy to me... and I'm a software engineer, the laziest creature to ever walk the earth. (Scripts do stuff for me!)

Now, how many states does your application have, to the point where you "don't want to id all states and track list of targets"?

Comment: no offense taken, you're right. I'm lazier than you are :) Being my worst critic, there are better ways to structure a program.

Anyway, the whole thing is moot. Once rumor got out that I was using flash/flex for dev, mgmt came in and forced me to switch to javascript. Good thing too, because my program is way faster to develop now. No waiting to compile one small change, and with the help of jquery+requireJS my program is as modular as an AS3 app. 

I'm happy with the results. Peace.